# My props aren't updated after action dispatched but state was updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-props

I have an avatar component :

```
const Avatar = (props) => {
let newInput = React.createRef();

const upload = async () => {
    let file = newInput.current.files
    await props.changeFile(file)
    console.log('PROPS:', props.file)
    console.log('FILE:', file)
}

return (
    <div className={mod.Avatar}>
        <form method="post" action="" encType="multipart/data">
            <label id={mod.l} htmlFor={mod.ava}><img src={ava} alt=''/></label>
            <input ref={newInput} type="file" id={mod.ava} name="ava" accept='image/*' onChange={upload} files={props.file}/><br />
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

Function from my reducer:

```
  case CHANGE_FILE:{
        console.log('ACTION.FILE', action.file)
        let newFile = action.file
        console.log('NEW STATE', {...state, file: newFile})
        return  {...state, file: newFile}
    }
```

This works for text, but when i'm using file input it isn't update props.

I logged it and can see that i sent new file to the state, but props still empty.
My console logs

```
ACTION.FILE FileList {0: File, length: 1}l
NEW.FILE FileList {0: File, length: 1}
NEW STATE {posts: Array(4), textAreaValue: "aa", file: FileList}
PROPS: 
FILE: FileList {0: File, length: 1}
```

Comment: setState is async.. and you logging in sync matter

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the problem or not, but don't use a ref here.  `onChange` will pass in a ChangeEvent argument.  Use `event.target.files` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Also, @DennisVash is sort of right.  The `props` you're logging are the ones of the current rendering of your component.  If you want to view what's being re-rendered, move the log outside of `upload()`.